# achartengine demo's budget chart didn't work as expected

Tags: achartengine

i download the achartengine demo from here :http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list
and after i started that demo,i find that not every chart paint as expected,when i click on the budget pie chart ,it didn't work and break out 
here is my log:

```
06-11 17:48:31.478: D/AndroidRuntime(1909): Shutting down VM
06-11 17:48:31.478: W/dalvikvm(1909): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a221f8)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:692)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:103)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:174)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10982)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10985)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10985)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2126)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:840)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1935)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1659)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2467)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-11 17:48:31.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1909):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can't catch the exception detail in code maybe because the exception didn't happen in the main thread.does anyone has the same experience? 
any answer related is welcome,thank you in advance!

Comment: I suggest you download a newer version here and see if you still get the exception: http://achartengine.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

This might not be directly related to the demo app for AChartEngine, per se.  However I have found that when building an application (which uses the AChartEngine library) in release mode using ProGuard. As stated in the android documentation for [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#configuring) there are situations which it finds difficult to analyse and mistakenly removes code that it thinks is unused. In this scenario when the library tries to draw the graph by calling onDraw it throws a NPE.

To overcome this I found that you had to customise the ProGuard configuration to instruct it to leave the AChartEngine classes alone by adding the following line to the proguard.cfg.

```
-keep class javax.** { *; }
```

Hope this helps someone.